# Sequential sum of a list of vectors

Tags: r

Let `x`, `y`, and `z` be vectors with an equal length. Assume that I would like to sum them sequentially, i.e., `x +y`, then `x+y+z`. Suppose I have a list of 20 vectors. Is there an easy way to do this?

```
 x <- c(1,2,3,45)
 y <- c(2,31,31,4)
 z <- c(3,4,54,6)
```

Here is my expected output:

```
>  s <- x+y
> s
[1]  3 33 34 49

>  z+s
[1]  6 37 88 55
```

Comment: `"Let x, y, and z be vectors with an equal length."` x has 5 elements, y,z have 4. Please pose a proper question, with **meaningful example data** and **expected outcome**.

Comment: @AndreElrico Thank you so much for your comment. This is a typo. Sorry. I will edit my question. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible route. Put your vectors into a list and fix their length to be the same. You can achieve this by padding NAs to all vectors to reach the same vector length as the maximum. The you can use `Reduce` with the argument `accumulate = TRUE` to apply the function sequentially, i.e.

```
l1 <- list(x, y, z)
l1 <- lapply(l1, `length<-`, max(lengths(l1)))

Reduce(`+`, l1, accumulate = TRUE)
#[[1]]
#[1]  1  2  3 45 34

#[[2]]
#[1]  3 33 34 49 NA

#[[3]]
#[1]  6 37 88 55 NA
```

**NOTE:** If your vectors are all the same length, then you can just put them in a list and go directly to `Reduce`, i.e. `` Reduce(`+`, list(x, y, z), accumulate = TRUE) ``

Comment: Thank you so much. Yes, they must have the same length. I have edited my question. I learn a new thing for the `Reduce` function.

Comment: So no need for handling length. You can go directly to the `Reduce` part